# Multiple combined if statements

Tags: vba, excel

I have looked but couldnt find anything that looked like a good fit to my problem.

My problem is that i have several helpercolumns that check certain values to decide if a condition is decided, not decided or replanned. 
My problem today is that if the conditions for replanned are meet, this will override delivered and not delivered.

IS there a way to combine these with AND or something similiar?

Thanks in advance

Code Below

```
If lskolumn > 0 Then
    dagensdatum = dataworksheet.Cells(Rad,lkolumn).Value 'Dagens datum för leveransen
    leveranssheet.Cells(i, 13).Value = IsWeekend(dagensdatum)  'Dagens datum för leveransen
    If leveranssheet.Cells(i, 12).Value >= 1 Then
        leveranssheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Delivered"
    Else
        leveranssheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Not Delivered"
    End If

    If leveranssheet.Cells(i, 13).Value <> leveranssheet.Cells(i, 7).Value Then
        leveranssheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Replanned"
    End If
End If
```

Comment: You call that code? I call it a dropped scrabble bag. Please format!

Comment: @A.S.H +1 if I could for the effort.

Comment: Why not do this directly on the worksheet? Much simpler that way.

Comment: @Bathsheba lol,  but the big problem remains... to know the correspondence between the code variables and the names in the text :)

Comment: I agree it's better to do it in the worksheet but you can simply move the `replanned` If statrement abouve the `Delivered` / `Not Delivered` If statement and then it will no longer override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I would advise to avoid nesting then look at the problem again in a nicer format.

```
If lskolumn > 0 Then
  dagensdatum = dataworksheet.Cells(Rad,     lkolumn).Value 'Dagens datum för     leveransen
  leveranssheet.Cells(i, 13).Value = IsWeekend(dagensdatum)  'Dagens datum för leveransen 
End If

If lskolumn > 0 && leveranssheet.Cells(i, 12).Value >= 1 Then
  leveranssheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Delivered"
End If

If lskolumn > 0 && !leveranssheet.Cells(i, 12).Value >= 1 Then
  leveranssheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Not Delivered" 
End If

If lskolumn > 0 && leveranssheet.Cells(i, 13).Value <> leveranssheet.Cells(i, 7).Value Then
  leveranssheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Replanned" 
End If
```

Comment: Code without documentation is practically useless.

Comment: I really appriciate the effort u guys put in! I am really thankful! I try to do my best with the knowledge i have regarding this at the moment so thanks for the input. What do u mean by doing this directly in the worksheet? Do u mean that i should write a formula?

Comment: Absolutely. As a rule of thumb, always use a formula if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your last `if` statement inside the first one like this:

```
If leveranssheet.Cells(i, 12).Value >= 1 Then
    If leveranssheet.Cells(i, 13).Value <> leveranssheet.Cells(i, 7).Value Then
        leveranssheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Replanned"
    Else
        leveranssheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Delivered"
    End if
Else
    leveranssheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Not Delivered"
End If
```

Please note: I'm not sure what the "Replanned" criteria are by your statement, but I think this is what you want to do.